# Uneven vertical spacing displaymath

Tags: spacing, equations

I would like to ask you why we have uneven vertical skips between the first two and last two vectors, coming from the source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\]
\[(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\]
\[(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\]
\end{document}
```

If I use more than 3 consecutive displaymath lines the same phenomenon happens: the vertical skip between the first two is considerably larger than the space between any further two lines. Any workarounds? I am using MikTex 2.9 with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Loading the `amsmath` package gives you even vertical spacing. However, consecutive displays should be avoided. A `gather` environment (from `amsmath`) could be used instead.

Answer (score 6):

Never use consecutive math environments. The correct output can be obtained by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\\
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\\
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The **amsmath** package has a bunch of environments for proper math typesetting, consult its documentation; you should have on your system the file `amsldoc.pdf` that contains it.

Comment: Note that consecutive display math environments would allow a pagebreak between them. With `gather*`, a page break is normally disallowed, but the workaround is to replace each ``\\`` with ``\displaybreak[0]\\`` or something like that.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, that's explained in the manual for `amsmath`. In my opinion, allowing arbitrary page breaks between displayed equations is bad and judgment should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have two or more consecutive lines of displaymath, you should seriously consider using the equation-grouping environments of the `amsmath` package. The basic equation-grouping environments of this package are `gather`, best if each line is a separate entity not particularly related to those that come before or after, and `align`, designed to let you align consecutive equations on some location, frequently (but not necessarily) an equal-sign. A line break between equations is created by the `\\` command. There are both numbered and unnumbered versions of these environments -- the latter are created by appending an asterisk to the environment name, e.g., `gather*` and `align*`. The following modified form of your MWE has consistent (and tight) spacing between the equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\\
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\\
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The amsmath package provides additional equation-grouping environments besides the two I've just mentioned, as well as many other commands that are very useful if you need to typeset math-related stuff. Its main user guide is the file [amsldoc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Before the first equation should be some "text", eg:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\[(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\]
%
\[(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\]
%
\[(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\]

\end{document}
```