# Remove excess space at end

Tags: macros, spacing

I realize that one should not have two consecutive display math equations as mentioned in [Uneven vertical spacing displaymath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/uneven-vertical-spacing-displaymath).  However, in my case, I have a macro that typesets two given macros in a specific manner and each may contain display math.  This sometimes results in excess space.

If I understand it correctly, in [this answer to excess vertical space in mdframed ending with display math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44147/4301), David Carlisle's mention of *"you could just detect a zero height box and remove stuff"* makes me think that it should be possible to write a macro that can remove any excess space at the end of text as passed to it. Unfortunately, I don't understand that code so can't easily adapt it.

My attempt to write such a macro below intuitively seems wrong, but *sort of* works.  But, in case #3 and #4 below the spacing is not correct.  What I would like is that `\RemoveSpaceAtEnd` removes any space at the end.  So if the parameter that is passed to it ends in a display math environment, that the `\belowdispalyskip` is `0pt` only for the **very last** display math, not for every the display math in that macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\RemoveSpaceAtEnd}[1]{% Need to figure out code here. Hack here almost works
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    #1%
}

\newcommand*{\MacroA}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
}

\newcommand{\MacroB}{%
    \begin{align*}
        e &= m c^2
    \end{align*}
}

\newcommand{\MacroC}{%
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}
}

\newcommand{\Print}[2]{%
    \noindent\RemoveSpaceAtEnd{#1}%
    \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
    \noindent\RemoveSpaceAtEnd{#2}%
    \hrule%
}

\begin{document}
\Print{\MacroA}{\MacroA}
\Print{\MacroA}{\MacroB}
\Print{\MacroB}{\MacroC}
\Print{\MacroB}{\MacroA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "write a macro that can remove" One issue is that inside a box (as in the other case) you can remove items from the end of the box with `\lastbox`, `\unskip` and friends, however on the main vertical list you can't, so the techniques have to be different. If you know how much space was added you can of course add a negative space to visually correct for it, but that's not really the same as actually removing things.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: For my particular case the problem really is just with a display math formula. If I could detect if text ended with display math or not then adding negative vertical space would probably do.

Comment: If a box ended with display math it will end with `\belowdisplayshortskip` or `\belowdisplayskip` so if you set those to a magic detectable value (by for example changing their value by something invisible like 1sp and seeing if the glue at the end has that value) then you can look at `\lastskip` and if it has either of those magic values act accordingly

Comment: answer below implements the scheme described in the comment above

Comment: Related Questions: [Excess vertical space in mdframed ending with display math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44131/4301), [Add \par only if last paragraph did not end with displayed math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103562/4301) and [How to check if last displayed content was displaymath / minipage ends on displaymath?
](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448856/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a working example of the algorithm sketched in the comments,hopefully it does what you meant:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\RemoveSpaceAtEnd}[1]{%
\begingroup
\advance\belowdisplayskip1sp
\advance\belowdisplayshortskip1sp
\par#1\par
\ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayshortskip
\typeout{display here (short)}%
\nobreak
\vskip-\belowdisplayshortskip
\else
\ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayskip
\typeout{display here \noexpand#1}%
\nobreak
\vskip-\belowdisplayskip
\fi
\fi
\endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\MacroA}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
}

\newcommand{\MacroB}{%
    \begin{align*}
        e &= m c^2
    \end{align*}
}

\newcommand{\MacroC}{%
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma
    \end{align*}
}

\newcommand{\Print}[2]{%

    \noindent\RemoveSpaceAtEnd{#1}%
    \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
    \noindent\RemoveSpaceAtEnd{#2}%
    \par\hrule

}

\begin{document}
\Print{\MacroA}{\MacroA}
\Print{\MacroA}{\MacroB}
\Print{\MacroB}{\MacroC}
\Print{\MacroB}{\MacroA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An updated version of this is at: [Add \par only if last paragraph did not end with displayed math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103562/add-par-only-if-last-paragraph-did-not-end-with-displayed-math).