# Add \par only if last paragraph did not end with displayed math

Tags: spacing, macros, equations, paragraphs

### Background:

I have named "sections" (*sections* for rest of this question) which are conditionally displayed or suppressed based on parameters. To simplify the test case below, these are controlled by the three `\def`s following `\begin{document}`.

Each of these *sections* should be able to control whether they are typeset in a new paragraph or are to continue from the last.
This seems to be working for 3/4 of the cases.
Where I run into a problem is if the last enabled *section* ended in a display math environment, *and* the following *section* wants to always be displayed as a new paragraph (that is *not* continue on as part of the previous paragraph as is the case for the `IntroDetails` paragraph.

### Problem:

The MWE below reproduces the problem case, and you can see that the `Summary` paragraph starts further down then it should.  To see this more clearly, you can see the other cases that work, which is any combination of commenting out *at least one* of the following:

```
\def\EndWithDisplayMath{}% 
\def\SupressIntroDetails{}%
```

So, it seems what I need is a macro that redefines `\par` if the last typeset content ended in display math.
I would like to add the intelligence to the `\NamedSection` macro so that each of the named content *sections* don't need to take into consideration if the previous typeset content ended with displayed math.

### Notes:

- In case it is relevant, the *sections* are *always* typset in the order they appear in the document, but each *section* can be typeset or suppressed independently of the others.
- I attempted to reproduce the problem within a `minipage` environment to make it easier to see the problem spacing, but things seems to work just fine in a `minipage`?

### References:

- I am using a *modified* version of the solution from [Remove excess space at end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45943/remove-excess-space-at-end) to eliminate the vertical space if the *section* ended with with a display math equation.  The modification was to remove the `\par` which is most likely related to the `\RemoveSpaceAtEnd` not quite working.

### Code:

```
\def\EndWithDisplayMath{}% Problem ONLY if BOTH of these are uncommented.
\def\SupressIntroDetails{}% 


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45943/remove-excess-space-at-end
\newcommand{\RemoveSpaceAtEnd}[1]{%
    \begingroup
        \advance\belowdisplayskip1sp
        \advance\belowdisplayshortskip1sp
        %\par% Removed this from solution from 45943
        #1%
        %\par% Removed this from solution from 45943
        \ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayshortskip
            %\typeout{display here (short)}%
            \nobreak
            \vskip-\belowdisplayshortskip
        \else
            \ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayskip
                %\typeout{display here \noexpand#1}%
                \nobreak
                \vskip-\belowdisplayskip
            \fi
        \fi
    \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NamedSection}{%
    m% {#1} = name for sub-section
   +m% {#2} = content ("+" can have para)
}{%
    \ignorespaces%
    \ifcsname#1\endcsname%
        \RemoveSpaceAtEnd{#2}%
    \fi%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\begin{document}

% Control which sections to display:
\def\Intro{}%
\ifdefined\SupressIntroDetails
\else
    \def\IntroDetails{}%
\fi
\def\Summary{}%

\NamedSection{Intro}{%
    First we introduce the topic.
    \ifdefined\EndWithDisplayMath
        \[
            E = mc^2.
        \]
    \fi
}%
\NamedSection{IntroDetails}{%
Followed by more intro details.
}%
%
% Leaving a blank line here works fine, except if "IntroDetails" are supressed.
\NamedSection{Summary}{%
%  Want this to start on its own line.
\par%  Using \par works fine, except if "IntroDetails" are supressed.
And finally summarize the topic.
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just thinking... What about `\everydisplay` setting *something*, `\everypar` *resetting* that (so that you can detect whether a paragraph *contained* a display anywhere)?  Then you only have to know whether it was the *last* thing.  And maybe (maybe?) this can be detected by comparing `\prevgraf` at the beginning of the (last) display in the paragraph and at the end of the paragraph - if the difference is 3, the display was the last thing.  Of course, this would need to tinker with `\everypar`, probably also `\par` - but something like this *might* work.

Comment: @mbork: I think David Carlisle's solution from [Remove excess space at end](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45943/remove-excess-space-at-end) is the key, but not sure why removing the `\par` from `\RemoveSpaceAtEnd` is a problem. Perhaps need the `\par` to be able to detect the last display skip.

Comment: Related Questions: [Excess vertical space in mdframed ending with display math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44131/4301), [Remove excess space at end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45943/4301), and [How to check if last displayed content was displaymath / minipage ends on displaymath?
](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448856/4301).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you just want to put my `\par` back and then

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\NamedSection}{%
    m% {#1} = name for sub-section
   +m% {#2} = content ("+" can have para)
}{%
    \ignorespaces%
    \ifcsname#1\endcsname%
        \RemoveSpaceAtEnd{#2}%
    \fi%
    \ignorespaces%afterend%
}
```

[image]

---

If you need the sections sometimes to be mid-paragraph then you can restrict the use of `\par` to the beginning of a horizontal list, which means it's either after `$$` or `\noindent` (or you are in an inner list where `\par` does nothing anyway) or you are doing something very sneaky.

```
\makeatletter

\advance\belowdisplayskip1sp
\advance\belowdisplayshortskip1sp
\newcommand{\RemoveSpaceAtEnd}[1]{%
        %\par% Removed this from solution from 45943
        #1%
        \def\next{}%
        \ifhmode\ifnum\lastnodetype=-1\par
          \let\next\@doendpe
        \fi% Removed this from solution from 45943
        \ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayshortskip
            %\typeout{display here (short)}%
            \nobreak
            \vskip-\belowdisplayshortskip
        \else
            \ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayskip
                %\typeout{display here \noexpand#1}%
                \nobreak
                \vskip-\belowdisplayskip
            \fi
        \fi
        \next
}
```

Comment: The reason the `\par`s were removed was that I want _each_ named _section_ to determine if it starts a new paragraph or not. Each _section_ is not necessarily a new paragraph. So, with the `\par` put back in `\RemoveSpaceAtEnd`, the version which has _both_ `\def\EndWithDisplayMath{}` and `\def\SupressIntroDetails{}` commented is incorrect.  Sorry for not making that explicit enough -- this is buried in the comments in the `Summary` section.

Comment: It is strange that the modified `\RemoveSpaceAtEnd` works fine in a `minipage`. I thought this was due to the modified `\parskip`, but that has no effect -- so, even restoring `parkskip` the results in a `minipage` are fine.

Comment: @PeterGrill Well not that strange as at the start of a minipage you are already in vmode so the first `\par` would do nothing anyway so removing it does no harm.

Comment: I don't see how the issue is with the first `\par` in `\RemoveSpaceAtEnd` if within a `minipage`. I belive it with the second one, at least in this MWE.  But both `\par`s in `\RemoveSpaceAtEnd` are problematic for me, in the general case.

Comment: @PeterGrill You mean you want to omit things mid paragraph in general?

Comment: Not sure I understand. I want each named _section_ to determine if it should have a `\par` before it or not.

Comment: @PeterGrill maybe I'm misled by the word "section" because I wouldn't expect a section to start I horizontal mode, which is why I asked if you need to omit parts of a paragraph eg individual words or phrases.  Trouble is I can't think off hand of a reliable way (in one pass) of detecting that you are just after display math without leaving hmode (or redefining every display math construct to leave a marker, but that would have other problems)

Comment: I defined at the top of the question that _section_ was a "named section" not the LaTeX `\section` -- I should have come up with a different name.