# Why does minipage have different top/bottom margins for math environments?

Tags: margins, minipage

My goal is to create a framed minipage environment that will contain text and math environments in varying combinations. I noticed that the top (and bottom) margin of the minipage is quite a bit larger if the first (and last) entry is a math environment (than it is if the first thing is normal text).

I tried to extract the relevant parts into a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\mathindent}{-.15em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
  \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.1\linewidth}
      XXX \\
      XXX
    \end{minipage}
  }
  \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.1\linewidth}
      \begin{align*}
        \textnormal{XXX}
      \end{align*}
      \begin{align*}
        \textnormal{XXX}
      \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
  }
\end{document}
```

Which results in:
[image: MWE output]

So why are there larger top/bottom margins for math environments and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: `align` is a display math environment and so insert some vertical spaces above and below.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Related Questions: [Spurious space above align environment at top of page/minipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/spurious-space-above-align-environment-at-top-of-page-minipage). Following question is relevant to removing the display math space at end of environment [Add \par only if last paragraph did not end with displayed math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103562/add-par-only-if-last-paragraph-did-not-end-with-displayed-math).

Comment: @Sigur the OP set the display spaces to 0, the white area isn't vertical space, it's a 1 line paragraph with just an indentation box