# How to check if last displayed content was displaymath / minipage ends on displaymath?

Tags: spacing, amsmath, conditionals, minipage

Is there a way to check if a minipage ends with display math? Or more generally, if the line above was a displaymath?

Background: I defined a command for a minipage-environment that fixes alot of spacings and adjusts to the current position (adapts identation in theorems, if its the first minipage in the theorem etc). Everything works fine except when a Minipage ends with \[ ... \]
Then it adds the wrong spacing compared to when the same would not be in a minipage. I wrote a command to fix the spacing, however i would like to have it automatically put when the minipage ends with one of the mathenvironments (displaymath and align* is what im using mostly).

So, I would like my minipagedefinition to execute something at the end like

```
\newcommand{\Mp}[1]{
  % Do various Dimension calculations
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\calculatedlength}\strut#1\strut\end{minipage}
  % Adjust spacing only if the last thing in the minipage was
  %   \[ ... \]
  \if@aftermathenv
    \spacecommand %this is just \vspace*{-1em}
  \fi
}
```

Is there a way to define such a \if@aftermathenv such that

```
\Mp{Text text text}
```

does not execute \spacecommand while

```
\Mp{Here is an equation
    \[ x = 3 \]
}
```

does execute the \spacecommand and adjust the spacing.

Comment: What happens if you add `\par \nointerlineskip \null` just before `\end{minipage}` in the definiton of your command?

Comment: It does not do the trick. My problem also is that i collected quite a few things manipulating with minipages and spacing in general. From beginning and ending minipages with \strut to various other changes.
Thats why I think it would be easiest to get a conditional, that checks if the page was ended by displaymath.

Comment: I think that, in order to get meaningful answers, you should explain better the background for your question.  For example, what “counts” as “something that follows the displayed equation”?  Another paragraph?  An explicit vertical space inserted by means of a `\vspace` command?

Comment: I updated the codesample and added some explanation, i hope it becomes clear now.

Comment: Mmh…  I’m afraid there’s something fundamentally wrong with the design of your `\Mp` command.  If you are placing a `\strut` (both at the beginning and) at the end of its argument, you are implicitly assuming that the command will be used only in horizontal mode, and that what is passed in the argument won’t cause TeX to exit that mode; in particular, the argument shuld not contain displayed equations *by your design* itself.  May I suggest that you describe what you are trying to achieve with the `\Mp` command?  Perhaps someone will suggest an approach that will prove better then yours.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not fully aware how \strut works, however it seems to do the trick for me that a minipage between two texts keeps the spacing as if there was no minipage, both with paragraphs or no paragraphs inbetween.
That solution comes from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349199/155748

Comment: As my current definition does everything exactly how I want it to behave, except having to manually call the `\spacecommand` at the end, I'd rather not write everything from scratch. However I'd still be interested to find out, if there is a way to automatize the `\spacecommand` depending on what the minipage ended on.

Comment: Related Questions: [Excess vertical space in mdframed ending with display math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44131/4301), [Remove excess space at end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45943/4301) and [Add \par only if last paragraph did not end with displayed math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103562/4301).  Hopefully one of those helps you.